# Modifier issue "traveling" or "who traveled"

Tags: modifiers

I have heard that modifier should be placed near the word or the phrase that modifies. In below sentence, the modifier  "traveling" is placed next to the word "tourists." I feel the below sentence is correct. But feedback of this states that it is wrong, because  *it implies that the buildings may have been the ones traveling to more well-known memorial museums*.
Can anyone explain the reason?

> Riddled with bullets, shattered by bombs, and hidden in alleys, the historic buildings in Lodz, Poland, were long ignored by **tourists, traveling** instead to more well-known memorial museums.

And the right answer is

> Riddled with bullets, shattered by bombs, and hidden in alleys, the historic buildings in Lodz, Poland, were long ignored by **tourists, who traveled** instead to more well-known memorial museums.

Comment: Regardless of the grammar points, buildings can't travel...

Comment: @user3169 why can't "traveling" be taken as a modifier that modifies "tourists" Doesn't that make sense?

Comment: I was just commenting on the logical fact. It is difficult to say the first example means something that is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "tourists, traveling" suggests the buildings were traveling. The issue is with the comma between those two words. WITH the comma, *traveling* refers to the subject of the sentence, the *buildings*. If you remove the comma, then the sentence is correct, because *traveling* now refers to *tourists*. Yes, you can also say "tourists, who traveled", but I don't think that's any better or worse than leaving out the comma.

Comment: "traveling" is near to tourist and not near to "historic buildings" then how can the meaning change?

Comment: This is a *sentence-ending present participle phrase*. You can read more about it here: 

http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/commas-with-participial-phrases

With the comma, the sentence-ending present participle phrase refers to the subject of the sentence ("buildings"). Without the comma, the sentence-ending present participle phrase refers to the closest noun ("tourist"). This is a grammar rule in formal English.